# Xamarin Forms how to bring an element to the front in the visual stack?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, layout

I'm trying to make an animation slide behind a label. The part that slides behind the label is dynamically generated through code. When this was statically and I used the RaiseChild() and LowerChild() I got the desired result. However, when I do the same thing now my title section moves underneath my detailsection which is not my intention.

```
<ContentView.Content>

    <StackLayout x:Name="layoutX" Spacing="0">
        <Frame x:Name="frameTitle" BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="10" Margin="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <Label x:Name="title" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </Frame>
        <Frame x:Name="frameDetails" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid x:Name="gridDetails" Padding="20,0" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
                <Frame x:Name="toggleDetails" Padding="0" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Green" HeightRequest="40">
                    <Label x:Name="toggleDetailsIcon" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="FaSolid" Text="{Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.ArrowUp}">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

In my code behind I add this to make adjust the visual stack.

```
     layoutX.LowerChild((View)layoutX.FindByName("layoutDetails"));
     layoutX.RaiseChild((View)layoutX.FindByName("layoutTitle"));
```

And I get this as result ...

[After bring the title section (red) to the front.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRJrP.png)

It should be this, but with the title section (red) arranged in the visual stack so that the description underneath slides behand it when the animation starts.

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilqPQ.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: where are "layoutDetails" and "layoutTitle" defined?  `FindByName` only works for XAML elements.  For elements defined in code you will need to use their reference.

Comment: To add to what Jason said: Create your own fields or properties to hold references to elements created in code, that you need to access later. Something like `private View layoutDetails;`  ... in constructor `layoutDetails = new ...`. When you need to use: `layoutX.LowerChild(layoutDetails);`